# Problem with this "minimalistic" python packaging that has an import in source code

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I'm not a programmer, and my audience/users are not programmers either. So I'm trying to have the most minimalistic setup for my python package. I liked this structure below, which is endorsed in this [video](https://youtu.be/GIF3LaRqgXo):

```
python-mypackage/
└── src/
    └── mypackage.py
```

The file mypackage.py:

```
import numpy as np

class myclass():
    def __init__(self, var_a, var_b):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b

    def mult(self):
        return np.matmul(self.var_a, self.var_b)
```

When I build this with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, with the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Test package',
    py_modules=["mypackage"],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
```

and install it with pip with `pip install -e .`, I get a NameError: name 'np' is not defined if I run

```
from mypackage import myclass

test = myclass([1,2], [3,4])
#Returns, NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

But for a reason I don't understand, if I have mypackage.py:

```
import numpy as np

def mult(var_a, var_b):
    return np.matmul(var_a, var_b)
```

And I build it and pip install it, the code below works:

```
from mypackage import mult

mult([1,2], [3,4])
#Returns 11
```

Is this behavior correct? Or do I have something funky in my installation? If it's normal, how do I correct the import failure of numpy in the class case (I know that if I do from mypackage import * will work, but I rather do the from mypackage import myclass)?

I'm sure there's maybe best programming practices with `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` files, but I rather stay away from them since I think they make the folder organization a little hard to follow for fellow non-programmers. But if there's no way around it without a `__init__.py` and/or `__main__.py` files, that would be good to know too.

Comment: In the method `mult` you should have `return np.matmul(self.var_a, self.var_b)`. -- I doubt it is related to the `NameError: name 'np' is not defined` error message, which I find strange, but the `self` is missing anyway. -- I don't know off the top of my head where that error message comes from, I should try to recreate this locally.

Comment: @sinoroc, yes that's correct, it's a typo in my toy example, I've corrected it. The error still stands since I just made that example to simplify my actual code that I'm getting the error in and that one I had the "self.var_a" correctly called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm under the impression that this was an installation error of some sort. When I did a new environment and reinstalled everything, I was able to call `myclass` without error using `from mypackage import myclass`